# ManyToMany (Symfony 6) querying issue

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following situation, two entities, "Actor" and "Movies" which are in a 1..* - 1..* (many to many) relationship. What I am trying to achieve is basically retrieving all the actor names for a movie based on the movie id and serializing this data as JSON (implicitly showing a JSON array in the target URL 'base/movies'.

- In plain SQL, this works "SELECT a.name FROM actor a INNER JOIN  movie_actor ma ON a.id = ma.actor_id INNER JOIN movie m on ma.movie_id = m.id WHERE movie_id = 7;"
- However, I have an issue when it comes to conversion to DQL or using a native query (please note that I have limited experience with Symfony :) ).
- Also, I am curious how would the other way around work, retrieving all movie title for a given actor based on the actor id.
- Database structure:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHMwW.png)
- The "Actor" entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ActorRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ActorRepository::class)]
class Actor implements \JsonSerializable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Movie::class, mappedBy: 'actors')]
    private $movies;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->movies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Movie>
     */
    public function getMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->movies;
    }

    public function addMovie(Movie $movie): self
    {
        if (!$this->movies->contains($movie)) {
            $this->movies[] = $movie;
            $movie->addActor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMovie(Movie $movie): self
    {
        if ($this->movies->removeElement($movie)) {
            $movie->removeActor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }


    public function jsonSerialize(): array {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'movies' => $this->movies,
        ];
    }
}
```

- The "Movie" entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MovieRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MovieRepository::class)]
class Movie implements \JsonSerializable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private string $title;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $releaseYear;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private string $description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private string $imagePath;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Actor::class, inversedBy: 'movies')]
    private $actors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReleaseYear(): ?int
    {
        return $this->releaseYear;
    }

    public function setReleaseYear(int $releaseYear): self
    {
        $this->releaseYear = $releaseYear;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImagePath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imagePath;
    }

    public function setImagePath(string $imagePath): self
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Actor>
     */
    public function getActors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->actors;
    }

    public function addActor(Actor $actor): self
    {
        if (!$this->actors->contains($actor)) {
            $this->actors[] = $actor;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeActor(Actor $actor): self
    {
        $this->actors->removeElement($actor);

        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'image_path' => $this->imagePath,
            'actors' => $this->actors,
        ];
    }
}
```

- The "MoviesController":

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

# Below, marked by the "use" keyword the class imports are defined.
use App\Entity\Actor;
use App\Entity\Movie;
use App\Repository\MovieRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\JsonSerializableNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class MoviesController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/movies', name: 'movies')]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
    {
//        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Movie::class);
//        $movies = $repository->findAll();
//        return new JsonResponse($movies, Response::HTTP_OK);

        $sql = 'SELECT a.name FROM Actor a INNER JOIN  movie_actor ma ON a.id = ma.actor_id INNER JOIN movie m on ma.movie_id = m.id WHERE movie_id = 7';

        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\Entity\Movie', 'm');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('App\Entity\Actor', 'a', 'm', 'actors', array('id' => 'actor_id'));
        return new JsonResponse($rsm, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to achieve this with `createQueryBuilder()`

The index function will be this :

```
class MoviesController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/movies', name: 'movies')]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
    {

    $qb = $entity_manager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb ->select('a')
        ->from(Actor::class, 'a' )
        ->join('a.movies', 'm')
        ->where('m.id = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier', 7)
    ;


    $actors = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    
    // Remaining logic here


    }
}
```

When you add the `->join('a.movies', 'm')`, Doctrine identify automatically the relationship between Actor and Movie entities and knows that there is a `movie_actor` table. The proof is when you go to the symfony profiler and you will see the exact same query that you want.

Query from the symfony profiler :

```
SELECT
  a0_.name AS name_1,
FROM
  actor a0_
  INNER JOIN movie_actor m2_ ON a0_.id = m2_.actor_id
  INNER JOIN movie m1_ ON m1_.id = m2_.movie_id
WHERE
  m1_.id = ?
```